# how do I save a javascript range in a database for later use?

Tags: javascript, dom, range

Suppose a user highlights a range, and I want to save the position information so I can highlight it in code at some future date.

The text he highlights is within an article node.

What information could I save to recreate his selection at some future date?  Perhaps I would want to color it with a green background at that future date.

I looked at some answers in stackoverflow, and I see that you can create a range if you have saved the "startnode" and "endnode", but you obviously can't save those in a database.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? If you have some code please show us so we can help you from there. You say you've checked some question, which questions in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That highlighted text should be a child of an element with *id*:

```
<span id="text_01" class="highlighted"></span>
```

Thus, you'll save in your database:

- The element id.
- Start character index.
- End character index.

With this information you should be able to highlight the whole text as you require whenever a given document is opened again.

Comment: That's an interesting answer.  Some of the tags will not have ids, since the html is posted in from other sites sometimes, but my code could add ids to every tag that lacks one and then this would work.

Comment: @GideonIsaac That's it!